# How can i display popup window

Tags: html, css

We want to have live chat on our website to help users. So we need to have a popup window located on the first page. By clicking on it a window should appear for chatting.

The problem is that when scrolling through the main page the popup window goes under the boxes of the main page. You can see it here:

[image]

and this is my code :

```html
<!-- mibew button -->
<a id="mibew-agent-button" style="left: 2.5%; bottom: 2.5%; position: fixed;" onclick="Mibew.Objects.ChatPopups['5b1cbf2d5cf9dd0c'].open();return false;" href="/mibew/index.php/chat?locale=en" target="_blank">
  <img alt="" src="/mibew/index.php/b?i=mibew&amp;lang=en" border="0">
</a>
<script src="/mibew/js/compiled/chat_popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Mibew.ChatPopup.init({
    "id": "5b1cbf2d5cf9dd0c",

    "url": "\/mibew\/index.php\/chat?locale=en",
    "preferIFrame": true,
    "modSecurity": false,
    "forceSecure": false,
    "width": 640,
    "height": 480,
    "resizable": true,
    "styleLoader": "\/mibew\/index.php\/chat\/style\/popup"
  });
</script>
<!-- / mibew button -->
```

I think we must add an HTML property inline `"style="left: 2.5%; bottom: 2.5%; position: fixed;"` but I'm not sure.

Could you help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `z-index: 1000;
position: relative;` property in the modal

Comment: I have tried this attribute , it's working just in mozilla firefox.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your modal window class="modal-custom", and add to your project css style with the content:

```
.modal-custom {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

To have your window at the center of the page.